# TabView selection resets to first tab on sheet presentation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabview

### Update:

Thanks to Harshil & Sumit for pointing me out that I was simply too dumb to realize that I was using `id()` instead of `tag()`. If there is anything you can learn from this question, it is this:

When you work alone on a project, you tend to go blind. You don't see your own mistakes. Do code reviews. Ask friends and colleagues to look over it. It's a great idea. ;)

### Original Question:

In my SwiftUI project I am using a `TabView` with a `$selection` Binding for being able to switch tabs programmatically.

**The problem is**: When I present a sheet on, for example, the second view contained in the `TabView` the selection is reset to the first tab.

For me this seems like a **SwiftUI bug** - but is there a **workaround**?

Below you find a working example that demonstrates the behaviour. (Tested with **Xcode 12.4**)

**How to test**: Go to the second tab, tap the button "Two" and you will see that you get back to the first tab. As soon as you remove the `selection` property from the TabView this does not happen any more.

Cheers
Orlando

```swift
enum TabPosition: Hashable {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

struct RootView: View {
    
    @State private var selection: TabPosition = .one
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            One()
                .tabItem { Label("One", systemImage: "1.circle") }
                .id(TabPosition.one)
            Two()
                .tabItem { Label("Two", systemImage: "2.circle") }
                .id(TabPosition.two)
            Three()
                .tabItem { Label("Three", systemImage: "3.circle") }
                .id(TabPosition.three)
        }
    }
}


struct One: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("One").padding()
    }
}

struct Two: View {
    
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Two") { isPresented.toggle() }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            Three()
        })
    }
}

struct Three: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Three").padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.tag()` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 1
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            One()
                .tabItem { Label("One", systemImage: "1.circle") }
                .tag(1)
            Two()
                .tabItem { Label("Two", systemImage: "2.circle") }
                .tag(2)
            Three()
                .tabItem { Label("Three", systemImage: "3.circle") }
                .tag(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insted of id **.id(TabPosition.one)** assign tag like this **.tag(TabPosition.one)**